# How to set the User field value from context?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql

I'm new to graphql and I have a GraphQL server with express. I'm trying to set the createdBy field from the context value. I'm passing the userId like below

```
app.use('/graphql', auth, userAuthCheck, graphlHTTP(req => ({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
  context: {
    userId: req.user._Id,
  },
})));
```

I have a resolver like this to validate the authentication

```
const checkAuth = (resolve, source, args, context, info) => {
    if (context.userId) {
        return resolve(source, args, context, info);
    }
    throw new Error('You must be authorized');
};
```

I use graphql-compose-mongoose to create my mutation functions

The resolver validates the authentication correctly
    eventCreateOne: EventTC.getResolver('createOne',[checkAuth]),

When creating events i want to set the createdBy field with the value from context.
How do I do this ? I would like to know the best practice on handling this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue.

```
const checkAuth = (resolve, source, args, context, info) => {
 if (context.userId) {
        args.record.createdBy = context.user._id;
        return resolve(source, args, context, info);
    }
    throw new Error('You must be authorized');
};
```

I simply updated the args before I passed to the next resolver which inserted the value correctly.